# Is the normalized simplicial bar construction of an operad a cooperad?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, operads

Suppose that $\mathcal{P}$ is a connected, unital operad in $\mathbb{k}$-vector spaces (or complexes), i.e. $\mathcal{P}(1)=\mathbb{k}$ and the unit map for $\mathcal{P}$ is the identity. One may form the simplicial bar construction $C^o_*(\mathcal P)$ on $\mathcal{P}$. This produces a simplicial symmetric sequence as follows. For the $n$-simplices, we set
$$
C^o_n(\mathcal P) = \mathcal {P}^{\circ n}.
$$
The inner face maps are induced from the operad structure on $\mathcal P$ and the outer face maps are induced from the natural augmentation on $\mathcal P$. The degeneracies are induced from the unit map of $\mathcal P$. One may take the chain complex modulo degeneracies of this simplicial symmetric sequence and obtain a dg-symmetric sequence $N(\mathcal P)$.

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301365), Fresse constructs a map
$$
B(\mathcal P) \to N(\mathcal P),
$$
where $B(\mathcal P)$ is the operadic bar construction (as in, for example, Loday-Vallette). He shows that it is a quasi-isomorphism of complexes of symmetric sequences.
The object $B(\mathcal P)$ is a dg-cooperad. My question is: is $N(\mathcal P)$ also a dg-cooperad, and if so, is the morphism of Fresse a morphism of cooperads? Same question for the dual statements.

My intuition says that this is a cooperad, using the maps
$$
\mathcal{P}^{\circ n} \to \bigoplus_{p+q=n} \mathcal{P}^{\circ p} \circ \mathcal{P}^{\circ q},
$$
but I haven't worked through all the checks.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  This is worked out carefully in [Michael Ching, *Bar constructions of topological operads and Goodwillie derivatives of the identity*, Geometry and Topology 9 (2005), 883-954].

Added later, after Conner Malin's comment ... The paper [Ginzburg, Victor; Kapranov, Mikhail. *Koszul duality for operads*, Duke Math. J. 76 (1994), no. 1, 203–272] is perhaps the first paper in this area.

Comment: It is Proposition 9.29 for anyone looking, though he actually cites Fresse's "Koszul duality of operads and homology of partition posets"

Comment: Thanks for the references. If I understand correctly, Ching constructs a topological cooperad (the topological analogue of B(P)) and shows that the geometric realization of the simplicial object I mention in the original post coincides with this topological symmetric sequence. But I couldn't tell whether he shows that there is a dg-cooperad structure on the chains N(P), which I think would amount to showing that the cooperad structure map on the topological cooperad takes simplices to smash products of simplices.

Comment: Proposition 9.29 just restates the theorem of Fresse; I couldn't find mention of additional structure on the normalized chains. If I understand the Ginzburg-Kapranov paper correctly, they only introduce the cooperad (or its dual operad) which I called B(P).